# perl script to sort a file in the same order as listed in another file?

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module

I want to sort a file content in a specific order that is followed in another file.For example,

Input File1:

dff_0_1:G11

dff_0_5:N_25

dff_0:G10

dff_0_3:G13

dff_0_2:G12

Input File2:

G13

G11

G12

G10

N_25

output File1:

dff_0_3:G13

dff_0_1:G11

dff_0_2:G12

dff_0:G10

dff_0_5:N_25

Here is the perl code i wrote, but its not working as i wish.

```
my @input_file2 = <IN2>;

chomp @input_File2;

while (<input_file1>) {

foreach my $i (0..$#input_File2){

print OUT43 if /(.+)\:\Q$input_File1[$i]\E/; 

}

}

close (IN33);

close (IN43);

close (OUT43);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `grep` for to do it. `grep` returns the matched element from an array, then construct the list for to store output of the grep. use `select` to write content of the print statement to a new file.

When using lexical file handler there is no need to close the file

```
open my $fh1, "<", "one.txt";
open my $fh2 , "<","two.txt";
open my $wh, ">","output.txt";
my @data1 = <$fh1>;
select ($wh);

while (my $line = <$fh2>)
{
    chomp $line;
    my ($sort_data) = grep{/$line$/} @data1;
    print "$sort_data";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of errors in your code.

1. You declare my @input_**f**ile2 array but chomp @input_**F**ile2
2. Is your `while (<input_file1>) {` 's "input_file1" a file handle?
3. You foreach $#input_File2, but use $input_File1 in regular expression.
4. You should loop file1 inside loop of file2

I edited your code with a little change:

```
            #!/usr/bin/perl

            open (IN33, "<1.txt") or die "can't open file 1.txt";
            open (IN43, "<2.txt") or die "can't open file 2.txt";
            open (OUT43, ">out.txt") or die "can't open file out.txt";

            my @input_file2 = <IN43>;
            my @input_file1 = <IN33>;

            chomp @input_file2;


            foreach my $i (@input_file2){
            foreach (@input_file1) {

            print OUT43 if /(.+)\:\Q$i\E/;

            }

            }

            close (IN33);

            close (IN43);

            close (OUT43);
```

Comment: you should also break the inter-loop on success.

Comment: Try to use lexical file handle it is no need to close the file :)